# Adding page into certain namespace at step creation

Tags: php, customization, mediawiki

I want to add the page in a certain namespace on step creation.
How it must look like: a dropdown with list of namespaces (required for checking) and after pressing "post" button page will be placed in selected namespace.

What i do:
- edit wikipage.php (function insertOn() )
- editeditpage.php on string 2242

And... I have error on posting "The Title object did not provide an article ID. Perhaps the page doesn't exist?"

Anybody do it?

Comment: Can you please provide your the relevant code?

Comment: Have you already tried the page creation extensions? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_creation_extensions

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things in your request:

- a dropdown to select categories during page creation;
- enforcement of category selection.

So I think you should address the two things separately:

- [install VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) to provide a [GUI for category addition](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:VisualEditor/User_guide#Editing_categories) (perhaps configure it to make the category selector more visible, but that's offtopic);
- [install AbuseFilter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter) and add a filter which disallows creation of a page without a category; in the error message put some friendly text to let users know they must use said feature.